# Postgres PL/pgSQL function to apply series of changes to a table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am looking to apply a data versioning approach to a customer profile table. In this case, the table will be created in a schema called `profile`. The main table is called `profile_v0`, which is the initial state of the customer profile, and have a primary key called `name`. From time to time, where will be changes captured as table `change_log_1`, `change_log_2` and so on.

Thus, the latest customer profile is actually `profile_v0` with changes applied sequentially from `change_log_1` to the latest change log. The change log can overwrite a previous record with the same primary key, or can add new record.

How do I write the PL/pgSQL function to achieve above ? I'm imagining the function will only take the schema name as parameter, and will identifies all the tables residing in it and act accordingly.

To explain with example.

```
## profile.profile_v0

name, industry
Ford, Automotive
KFC, Food
7 Eleven, Retail
Google, Hardware
Microsoft, Software
```

...

```
## profile.change_log_1

name, industry
Google, Advertising
IBM, Services
```

...

```
## profile.change_log_2

name, industry
Cisco, Technology
KFC, Retail
```

At this point, the latest customer profile (could be a materialized view in different schema) should be:

```
name, industry
Ford, Automotive
7 Eleven, Retail
Microsoft, Software
Google, Advertising
IBM, Services
Cisco, Technology
KFC, Retail
```

Could this be implemented without PL/pgSQL? Note that the number of change logs will keep to increase.

Comment: If you use a materialized view, you have to note that for it to show updated data you have to re-materialize it every time. If you need updated data 'on the fly' you would need to use PL and a table to insert the view, this is called `Eager Materialized View` or `Lazy Materialized View`. If you don´t need it to be updated, it should be enough with a materialized view

Comment: seriously look at `pg_temporal`. don't try to reinvent this wheel.